# How to remove and add back navigationBar shadow?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

if I remove navigationBar shadow:

`self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()`

how I can add back this shadow?

Comment: You need to put this logic in viewWillAppear method of ViewControllers  For add/update/delete any of behaviour of navigationBar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar/1624963-shadowimage).

> The default value is nil, which corresponds to the default shadow
>   image.

So it should be enough that you set

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//Extension 
  extension UINavigationBar {

    func shouldRemoveShadow(_ value: Bool) -> Void {
    if value {
        self.setValue(true, forKey: "hidesShadow")
    } else {
        self.setValue(false, forKey: "hidesShadow")
    }
  }
 }
 //Use in view controller.
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shouldRemoveShadow(true)
```