# SwiftUI - iOS17 - Hide/remove navigationBar shadow from single view (not globally)

Tags: swiftui, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to remove the shadow/bottom line of the navigationBar in one single view.
Saw many answers around but none helped me (or, probably, I'm doing something wrong).
Many solutions remove the shadow globally but I'm interested in removing it only from a specific view.

[Tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51647452/how-to-remove-and-add-back-navigationbar-shadow) but didn't work for me.
[Tried this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76359951/ios16-remove-the-separator-line-of-navigation-bar-in-swiftui) too but no luck.

I'm probably missing something but can't figure it out.
My app works from iOS 16 on so I'm not interested in solutions covering older iOS versions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best idea as in if you have any other workaround it'd probably be better, but here's a possibility using [Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/swiftui-introspect):

```
YourTopLevelView()
    .introspectNavigationController { controller in
        controller.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
    }
```